# What is the difference between the class "Class" in the Java API and the "class" keyword?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the Java class `Class` (which extends `Object`) and the `class` keyword (the word that is used to create a class)?

Comment: `Class` (title case) is a class in java and `class`(all lowercase) is keyword

Comment: @user3218114 I think the OP already knows that much.

Comment: Do you mean the difference between `a.class` and `a.getClass()`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In programming, **reflection** is the ability of a program to modify its own structure and behavior at runtime through analysis of runtime details, such as the actual implementing class of an object instance. The `Class` class is a part of the Java API for the purposes of reflection. Whereas the `class` keyword is a structure of the Java language marking the definition of a new class, the `Class` class is used to type variables and parameters as classes themselves. It's a way for the program to use class definitions themselves as objects to program around (you can programmatically enumerate over the class' public methods, for example).

Additionally, any instance `o` of type `Object` (that is, any object in Java at all) inherits the `getClass` instance method. This yields the actual runtime class of the object, irrespective of the compile-time code-stated class of the variable the object is stored in. For example, for some defined class `X`:

```
Object o = new X();
Class<?> type = o.getClass();
```

`type` will now be a reference to the `X` class itself, which matches the `Class<?>` generic description because the `X` class is in fact an instance of type `Class<X>`.

Every defined class also has one static variable called `class` referring back to the class itself. Calling `getClass` on an instance of class X will return the same `Class<X>` instance as that class' `class` static variable:

```
("some string").getClass() == String.class
```

It is worth noting that the primitive types all have a static `class` variable as well even though they are not Objects. It is also worth noting that a primitive type's `class` is not the same as the `class` of its [wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class):

```
int.class != Integer.class
```

Comment: The `class` keyword is also usable to get the `Class` of an object. Furthermore it's possible to get the `Class`-objects of primitive types (`int.class`). Consider to mention it.

Answer (score 2):

`Class` is a Java class just like `Object` and `String` are classes.

On the other hand, if we say:

```
Class<?> c = String.class;
```

What we get in return is a `Class` object of type `String`:

```
Class<String>
```

In short, both are essentially the same, but you can keep a reference of a `String.class` object using the `Class` class.

They're used for Java reflection which you can learn more about here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/

Answer (score 1):

`Class` is a "Java class" that provide methods to manipulate "Java class" while `class` is a Java keyword used to declare a "Java class"

Answer (score 0):

`Class` is a Java class type (that extends the Object class, as you said), "an extensible program-code-template for creating objects, providing initial values for state (member variables) and implementations of behavior (member functions, methods)." - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_programming%29)

On the other hand, `class`, is a keyword, i.e. a reserved word by the language compiler (or interpreter, in other cases) that can not be used as an identifier or any other use. This specific keyword is used to declare custom class types.

Comment: Please suggest any improvements to the answer, if downvoted or have to add anything.

Answer (score 0):

`Class` objects are `Objects` of special types.. of class `java.lang.Class` used to represent class definiton.
class keyword is a keyword used to represent classes where you can put methods and variables.The most important thing to do with a Class Object is to perform **Reflection API**,it can be used to dynamically create objects,invoke methods and introspect them.You can also load multiple versions of a classes using `java.lang.ClassLoader`